# linq to sql show only two of the three columns in datagrid

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm new in linq to sql. I can do some primitive queries.

I have a table TotalDoc with fields [TotalID] int, [TotalDate] datetime and [TotalAmount] float

```
var items = from i in v.db.TotalDoc
            orderby i.TotalID descending
            select i;

dataGridView.DataSource = items;
```

How do I construct a query that will return only ID and Date fields?

Comment: You should accept iondens answer if it works for you. It is the nice thing to do on SO.

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = (from i in v.db.TotalDoc
            orderby i.TotalID descending
            select new {i.TotalID, i.Date}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize new Property like this

```
var items = (from i in db.TotalDoc
             order by i.TotalID descending
             select new { ID = i.TotalID, NewDate = i.Date}).ToList();
```